# Laravel/Eloquent ORM - retrieve only referenced records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

I have a many-to-many relationship which I resolved with an intersection table. 
So table A and B are connected through AxB. 
A and AxB are 1-n and B and AxB are 1-n.

The actual names of the tables:

```
   table A = extensiontables_registry
   table B = ad_groups
   table AxB = extensiontables_registryxad_groups
```

You can see the logical datamodel here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qHHR.jpg

Ive put the part we are talking about right now into a red frame.

Now, I have the following line of code in my backend-API:

```
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findMany($ids)->pluck('extensiontable_name')->toArray();
```

To keep things short, the `$ids` contains all the ids from "ad_groups". These I've gotten from a fetch which works as intended. 
The `$ids` contains these values/ids according to my logs:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12]
```

Now, the extensiontables_registryxad_groups currently looks like this:

```
 select * from extensiontables_registryxad_groups;
+-----------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| extensiontables_registry_id | ad_group_id | created_at | updated_at |
+-----------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|                           1 |           8 | NULL       | NULL       |
|                           2 |           8 | NULL       | NULL       |
+-----------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

And the extensiontables_registry looks like this:

```
+----+-----------------------+------------+------------+
| id | extensiontable_name   | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-----------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | extensiontable_itc    | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | extensiontable_sysops | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | test                  | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-----------------------+------------+------------+
```

And now the problem is that my codesnippet from above:

```
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findMany($ids)->pluck('extensiontable_name')->toArray();
```

returns me this result:

```
 array (
  0 => 'extensiontable_itc',
  1 => 'extensiontable_sysops',
  2 => 'test',
)
```

So the codesnippet does NOT do what I want it to do. It should only fetch me the names of those extensiontables which have IDs which exist on the very same record(s) in extensiontables_registryxad_groups with IDs from my inputarray above. So The result I currently would expect would be this:

```
 array (
  0 => 'extensiontable_itc',
  1 => 'extensiontable_sysops'
)
```

I am pretty new to laravel and eloquent, so I dont really know what I did wrong in my codesnippet. I also have no idea what I can do to get this working as intended ^^

For the sake of completeness, I'll show you my eloquent models/classes for this arrangement of tables, just in case you might need it:

AD_Group.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ad_group extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'name'
  ];

  /**
   * Hides pivot from return queries.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
    'pivot'
  ];

  /**
   * Many-To-Many relationship with User-Model.
   */
  public function Ad_users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ad_user', 'Ad_usersxad_groups', 'Ad_group_id', 'Ad_user_id');
  }

  public function extensiontables()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\extensiontables_registry', 'extensiontables_registryxad_groups');
  }

}
```

extensiontables_registry.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Extensiontables_Registry extends Model
{

  /**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $table = 'Extensiontables_Registry';

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'extensiontable_name'
  ];



  /**
   * Many-To-Many relationship with User-Model.
   */
  public function Ad_groups()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ad_group', 'extensiontables_registryxad_groups');
  }
}
```

I would be really thankful if you could help me or at least give me a hint what to look out for in order to find information on leveraging the methods of laravel/eloquent accordingly ^^ If you need any more info, ask right away :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you got things a little mixed up.

what this query does:

```
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findMany($ids)->pluck('extensiontable_name')->toArray();
```

is access the `extensiontables_registry` table and get records with the same array of `$ids` you sent.

But it will **NOT** take in consideration the relationship with `extensiontables_registryxad_groups` table **because** you didn't explicitly specify it in the query.

What you should add is `has('relationship name')` which get the records of this model that only has a corresponding Foreign key in `relationship name'` in your case `Ad_groups`

So in this case the query would look like this:

```
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::has('Ad_groups')->pluck('extensiontable_name')->toArray();
```

Comment: I currently get this error when using your query:
"[2020-05-11 06:35:09] local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'extensiontables_registryxad_groups.extensiontables__registry_id' in 'where clause' in E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\database\Connection.php:331
"

Also, your query doesn't use my set of IDs. I dont want to get ALL records from registry which reference records from groups. Instead, only those records from registry which reference the records from groups with one of these specific IDs from $ids array

Comment: @Narktor you have a typo in `extensiontables__registry_id` two under-scores  after `extensionables`, becuase laravel adds an extra underscore automatically to relationship keys, so you need to manually specify the Foreign keys in the relationships between your models **extensiontables_registry** & **AD_Group** this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) will help you.

Comment: @Narktor Regarding the `$ids` you can add a `whereIn('id',$ids)` clause to your query to filter the desired `$ids`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can get there  using join:

```
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::whereIn('id', $ids)
->join('extensiontables_registryxad_groups','extensiontables_registryxad_groups'.'extensiontables_registry_id','extensiontables_registry.id')
  ->select('extensiontables_registry.extensiontable_name')->get()->all();
```

please note you can avoid repeated results using 'distinct';

Comment: Currently I get this error with ur code:
"local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::Ad_groups does not exist. in E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\support\Traits\Macroable.php:103
"

Comment: i think we could simplify things more ... using direct way, i have updated my answer, please let me know if it helps